# where is the itunes "podcast discovery" widget?

Tags: api, widget, itunes

I would like to generate a widget via this site:

```
http://widgets.itunes.apple.com/builder/
```

it has "Album Discovery","Book Discovery" and also "Movie Discovery". Every one of those widgets can display a unique "item" like a album with all its tracks. But why is there not a "podcast discovery"-widget?!?! I need a widget which shows the name and maybe the author of the podcast and every track within this podcast. Is there any possibility to work around this problem? I tried to take the "playlist discovery" widget and put a podcast "id" into the request. But nothing happens actually by pressing the play button:

```
http://widgets.itunes.apple.com/widget.html?c=us&brc=FFFFFF&blc=FFFFFF&trc=FFFFFF&tlc=FFFFFF&d=asdf&t=asdf&m=song&e=song&w=250&h=300&ids=886856414&wt=playlist&partnerId=&affiliate_id=&at=&ct=
```

Is there anything I can do to get a podcast-widget, which displays me the tracks of a podcast?! Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this one here which solves my Problem.

http://tommarch.com/strategies/tutorials/adding-a-podcast-player/